# NSTimer, NSBlockOperation NSInvocation or NSOperation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to make a call to my server fetches some data every 30 data that should be used to display annotation on a MKMapView. I have researched about it, but I'm still unsure which to use?

Some guidance please. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using an NSTimer, perform a selector and in your selector launch an NSOperation to perform the download. Use KVO to observe for isFinished or use delegates with your NSOperation :)